# How to mobile optimize wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, width

My wordpress blog (workmoneyfun.com) is on Genesis Framework Prose Theme which is fully mobile responsive. However, I increased the width of website content area which has resulted in non-optimized for mobile. I had added the following codes to increase width.

```
body {
background: #f5f5f5;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1080px;
}

#inner {
width: 1070px;
padding: 0 10px;
}
.content-sidebar #content-sidebar-wrap {
width: 1040px;
}
.content-sidebar #content {
width: 680px;
}
.sidebar {
width: 320px;
}
.full-width-content #content {
width: 1000px;
}

.footer-widgets-1, .footer-widgets-3 {
width: 330px;
}
.footer-widgets-2 {
width: 280px;
}
```

How do I make my site mobile optimized with the current increased width area? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use % instead of px, use media query for the responsive.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a non-technical person so didn't get you. I had copied above code from wordpress tutorials to increase width. Any link for tutorial for your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: if you search for keywords media query css in google there are pretty good tutorials on how to work with it. for eg  (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)